# User needs to connect to the Internet to use my app?

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

I want to create an app to prepare for exam,with the several thousand questions.I want to use Parse. My question is : Can future user use my app without connecting to the Internet? (xcode,swift)

Comment: Depends entirely how you build it. It's possible I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will be of use to you: https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-saving-objects-offline

You can cache the questions and or answers on the device so they can use it without an internet connection for a period of time which is where `saveEventually()` comes from but if it is going to be connected to the Parse backend they will need an internet connection. It is not practical to build it in such a way though. Chances are your user will have an internet connection...it is 2016 after all.